# Prove that the equation $x^{15} + 7x^{3} - 5 = 0$ has exactly one real solution

Tags: functions

> Prove that the equation $x^{15} + 7x^{3} - 5 = 0$ has exactly one real solution.

A hint that has been given by the teacher is to analyze the function $f(x) = x^{15} + 7x^{3} - 5$.

Answer (score 8):

Hints:

Do what your teacher says, and observe:

(1) The equation is a polynomial one of **odd degree** and thus it has at least one real solution;

(2) $\;f'(x)=15x^{14}+21x^2\;$ is a non-negative function, thus...

Comment: Why couldn't you just use the rule of signs?

Comment: First, because I think it is way easier and simpler this way (though not more elementary...). Second, the rule of the signs is pretty unwidely unknown: even many university students haven't heard of it. Third, in this case this rule only serves to deduce the existence of a *positive* root, yet no info for negative ones as the number of sign changes of $\;f(-x)\;$ is zero...

Comment: Since there are no sign changes in $f(-x)$, we can conclude there are no negative real roots _at all_. (What were you expecting, $-2$ negative roots?) I've written up an answer that uses the rule.

Answer (score 4):

If $0\le a<b$ show that $a^{15}<b^{15}$, and similarly $7a^3<7b^3$.

So $a^{15}+7a^3 < b^{15}+7b^3$. So the function $g(x)=x^{15}+7x^3$ is an increasing function. Check that $g(0) = 0$ and $g(1)=8$. So $g$'s values change from $0$  to $8$ when $x$ varies from 0 to 1. Being continuous and increasing there is exactly an $x_0\in(0,1)$ such that $g(x_0)=5$. That $x_o$ is the root for $f(x)$. As $g$ is increasing it cannot take the value 5 again. SO that is the only root.

Answer (score 3):

We will use [Descartes's rule of signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs) to determine the number of positive and negative roots of $x^{15}+7x^3-5$. (Zero is obviously not a root.)

1. The non-zero coefficients of the polynomial *per se* change sign exactly once. Therefore, it has exactly one positive root.
2. Replacing $x$ with $-x$ we get $-x^{15}-7x^3-5$, which has no sign changes at all. Therefore the original polynomial has no negative roots.

In conclusion, the original polynomial has exactly one real root, and it is positive.